# Can I use 14/2 wire on a 2500 watt heater

Tags: electrical

Can I use 14 Guage wire on a 2500 watt baseboard heater.

Comment: Is this heater on a dedicated circuit, or sharing a branch circuit with other heaters? Also, is it 120V or 240V?

Answer (score 4):

Heaters must be derated to 125% when provisioning service for them. So 2500 watts gets derated to 3125 watts and that is what you must provision.

That is within the 3600 watt capacity of a 15A/240V circuit.

Comment: 12/2 & 20Amp breaker is the standard, but I think 14/2 would work, but I think I read to still use a 20Amp breaker somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I think you would use the watts/voltage = amps.  Keep in mind you should only use 80%. So if it is 120v then you are slightly over 20A and would need 10 gauge

Comment: Many baseboard heaters are 240V -- a 2.5kW 240V heater only pulls just over 10A, which is fine on 14AWG even with the 125% factor for continuous loads.

Comment: I have never heard of having to use 10Ga w/ Baseboards, usual is 12/2 but I've used 14/2 fine. I accidentally used 14/2 and am debating replacing w/ 12/2 but im probably fine. (Has been working fine anyway!)